# Knowledge Article rich text field missing editing toolbar

Tags: knowledge, user-interface

**Use case:**

1. Rich text field added to Knowledge Article Type `Foo`
2. User (sysad) verifies Knowledge Article can be created. RTF tool bar present
3. Sysad grants Permission `Manage Articles` to User Smedley
4. Sysad ensures User Smedley has `Knowledge User` checkbox true on `User` record.
5. Adequate Knowledge Licenses exist

**User Smedley**, when creating a Knowledge Article sees this:

[image]

**User (sysad)** sees this:

[image]

Comment: I am having the same issue (rich text editor not available in page layout for Article Types), but Accessibility Mode is unchecked in BOTH User Details and My Settings. No luck thus far. Something else also causes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This took me a while to figure out (first time with Knowledge) as I went down blind alleys on Permissions for a while.*

Rich text tool bars are not available to users who have Accessibility Mode checked on their User record. And, as of Winter 17, Knowledge is not available in LEX.

*And, by chance, to verify my setup work, I initially selected a user (Smedley) who required Accessibility Mode.*

[image]